# Learning Angular for the first time - version 2 or 4?

Tags: javascript, angular

I recently took the decision start learning Angular javascript framework. According to the angular.io website, the current stable version is v4.4.6 as of today.

Over the past couple of weeks, I have perused articles discussing the differences among the various versions of Angular (AngularJS, Angular 2 and Angular 4). My understanding is that versions 2 and 4 are a complete departure from AngularJS. But again, v4 contains obviously breaking changes in comparison with v2.

Now, since v4 is only a few months old, and the majority of learning resources available are based on v2, should I go ahead and begin with v2 at this point?
I guess the right approach for me should be hinged on how fundamental the differences between v2 and v4 actually are!

So, to restate the question: would it be worth it to plunge into the abundant Angular 2 learning materials around, or should I restrict myself to Angular 4, looking forward into the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A month ago I started learning Angular4. I didn't have any issues solving my problems. There is more than enough information out there. Angular.io also contains a lot of tutorials that will help you get started. The only advice I can offer, is that if you ever touch http requests, use HttpClient. Angular4 has multiple http modules and HttpClient is the latest (added in 4.4.3). I also didn't get other http modules working.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for the helpful commment. So you mean you had NO PREVIOUS EXPERIENCE with Angular?

Comment: Indeed. I just started using Angular.